# Modifier application order

Tags: modifiers

What order are these modifiers applied in?
I would think the Armature would be applied first, followed by Lattice. Or is it the other way around?

[image]

Comment: Modifiers are applied from top to bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender modifiers are always calculated from top to bottom, where on top is the raw unmodified base mesh, and modifiers are calculated from the first in the list down to the last one at the bottom, as stated in the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#the-modifier-stack)